# Comparar Objetos JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una cola de propiedad. Mi cola trabaja excelente ya que recibe datos GENERICS de tal modo si comparo enteros, string esta todo OK. Ahora tengo que meter a la cola Objetos de una clase llamada "Topico" para lo cual en dicha clase cree mi constructor y los correspondientes gets y sets.
La clase tiene las variables 
int identificador; 
int puntajeActual; 
int puntajeDiferencia;

```
public boolean esMayor(Topico obj1, Topico obj2) {
    if (obj1.getPuntajeActual() > obj2.getPuntajeActual()) {
        return obj1 > obj2;//Error
    }
```

}

Por el momento solo necesito saber cual es el mayor 
El problema esta que al hacer esta comparación me sale el error:

> "bad operand types for binary operator".

El mismo código con `Integer`, `String`, etc. me funciona bien.

Comment: `El mismo código con Integer, String, etc. me funciona bien`. No, con `String` no funciona.

Comment: No funciona por que los operadores binarios de comparación `<, >, <=, >=, ==` realizan comparaciones sobre tipos de datos numéricos y no sobre objetos como pretende hacerlo en la linea `return obj1 > obj2;` Una solución es la respuesta dada por ManuelDomínguez.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es un método boolean entonces ha de devolver un boolean.

```
public boolean esMayor(Topico obj1, Topico obj2) {
   if (obj1.getPuntajeActual() > obj2.getPuntajeActual()) {
       return true;
   } 
   return false;
   }
```

También el `.getPuntajeActual()` debe devolver un carácter numérico en forma de int, long, double...